# Get the selected value of Ajax:ComboBox using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

i want to get the selected value of a asp.net `Ajax:ComboBox`

```
<Ajax:ComboBox ID="Cmb_Class" runat="server" MaxLength="0"></Ajax:ComboBox>
```

The combobox is populated from database 
i tried this but it's not working;

```
var class = $("#<%=Cmb_Class.ClientID %>option:selected").val();
```

And that is because at runtime, the generated html is

```
 <div id="Cmb_Class" class="WindowsStyle" style="display:inline-block;">
    <table id="Cmb_Class_Table" class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:5px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td class="ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer"><input name="ctl00$CPH_Content$Cmb_Class$Cmb_Class_TextBox" id="Cmb_Class_TextBox" autocomplete="off" style="width: 180px; margin: 0px;" type="text"></td><td class="ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer"><button style="height: 25px; width: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; visibility: visible;" id="Cmb_Class_Button" type="button"></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table><ul id="Cmb_Class_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: 10000; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: 230px; position: absolute; height: 266px;"><li>--Select--</li><li>1-A</li><li>1-B</li><li>1-C</li><li>1-D</li><li>1-E</li><li>1-F</li><li>1-G</li><li>2-A</li><li>2-B</li><li>2-C</li><li>2-D</li><li>3-A</li><li>3-B</li><li>3-C</li><li>3-D</li><li>4-A</li><li>4-B</li><li>4-C</li><li>5-A</li><li>5-B</li><li>6-A</li><li>6-B</li><li>7-A</li><li>8-A</li><li>9-A</li><li>10-A</li><li>11-A</li><li>12-A</li><li>Nursery-lily</li><li>Nursery-sun</li><li>Nursery-moon</li><li>Nursery-sky</li><li>Nursery-tulip</li><li>Nursery-roze</li><li>Nursery-star</li><li>Play Group-Blue</li><li>KG-1</li><li>KG-2</li><li>KG-3</li><li>KG-4</li><li>KG-5</li><li>KG-6</li><li>KG-7</li><li>KG-8</li><li>KG-9</li><li>KG-10</li><li>KG-11</li><li>KG-12</li></ul><input name="ctl00$CPH_Content$Cmb_Class$Cmb_Class_HiddenField" id="Cmb_Class_HiddenField" value="0" type="hidden">
</div>
```

As, you can see, it generates table. 

**So, how do i get the selected value and check if the value is null or not using jQuery;**

Comment: Have you tried `$("#Cmb_Class_TextBox").val()`?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1727253.aspx/1

Comment: that link is through asp.net ajax, i want it through jquery

Comment: Have you also tried `$("#Cmb_Class_HiddenField").val()`? When you select an item, does the `li` item change (new class?, ...)? Look at the input fields, are they containing the values?

Comment: yeah, @Eich, it works. the problem was _HiddenField that is appended to control by asp.net runtime. post your answer so that i could accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hidden input field to get the selected value.

```
$("#Cmb_Class_HiddenField").val()
```

Comment: i tried this `var classes = $('#<%= Cmb_Class.ClientID %>_HiddenField');` and it works :D